# create activity indicator when navigate in webView using webkit in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, webview, webkit, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to create a wkwebview in my iOS app, and I want to add an activity indicator to it. I want when we click all the button or part in the webview, it will appear the activity indicator. Can you give me some code to do this? Here's my code right now. It only show the indicator when start load the website but when we click at the process, the indicator not appear.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,WKNavigationDelegate,UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)

        self.view.addSubview(self.webView)

        let url:URL = URL(string : "https://www.facebook.com/")!
        let urlRequest : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(urlRequest)

        //activity indicator
        self.webView.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

        //refresh
        webView.scrollView.bounces = true
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.refreshWebView), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        webView.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear( animated )

        let url:URL = URL(string : "https://www.facebook.com/")!
        let urlRequest : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(urlRequest)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

    @objc func refreshWebView(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
        print("refersh")
        sender.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will help to add activity indicator in Navigation Bar. So no need to create any subviews. This works with Swift 4.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ContactVC: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView

        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: activityIndicator)
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(barButton, animated: true)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func showActivityIndicator(show: Bool) {
        if show {
            // Start the loading animation
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        } else {
            // Stop the loading animation
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }

    //MARK:- WKNavigationDelegate
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Start to load")
        showActivityIndicator(show: true)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Finish to load")
        title = webView.title
        showActivityIndicator(show: false)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        showActivityIndicator(show: false)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        showActivityIndicator(show: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement didStartProvisionalNavigation delegate function.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: tq very much sir :)